# Does the Android GPS drain battery when trying to get first fix?

Tags: android, gps

I noticed something odd on my HTC Desire S Android phone: If the GPS cannot get a fix the GPS icon in the notification bar stays blinking the whole day. Even if I force stop all applications using the GPS the icon keeps on blinking.

Blinking means that it hasn't gotten a fix. It seems like the GPS is continuously trying to get that first fix. If I cannot shut off the GPS during initial fix, does it still drain the battery as if it had a fix?

Comment: This happens both when I start and force stop my own application as well as when I start and force stop Google Maps.  My application registers a location listener, but I call `locationManger.removeUpdates(this)` in the `onDestroy()` method of the listener.  I was under the impression that this is called during a force stop. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

unregistered the LocationListener in your application using removeUpdates() method . you must have forgot this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have unregistered all of the location listener; This is a known problem I've seen it before. It is really hard to say what happened without logs. There could be two possibilities :

- More likely one: The stop GPS blinking icon notification to the status bar somehow got lost. I've seen this bug before (once in 500 runs). In this case, GPS has beed stopped, It is a bug in [StatusBarPolicy.java](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/status/StatusBarPolicy.java) or [GpsLocationProvider.java](http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/fd9f42a6967370490cd2c66e628ccbf2eacc4a4b/location/java/com/android/internal/location/GpsLocationProvider.java) . The intent GPS_FIX_CHANGE_ACTION is somehow missed.
- It is a rare case that GPS is actually running, that may be due to a defect in the GPS chipset used in HTC